# AJAX fails on invalid token in Prestashop 1.7.2.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, token, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on Admin module and I have to add field to a product page. Since product page cannot be extended in this version, I have to work on hooks and Javascript. My issue is, I've done what I was supposed to do, however I'm failing to go through token validation.

I'm on site https://myserver.eu/admin/index.php/product/form/12?_token=TyEoISTXRQCH5Bv-Odi9IpTihpvzVIjFn7tQfDZDj6Q#tab-step3

And sending AJAX to https://myserver.eu/admin/index.php?controller=AdminMyModuleController&method=ajaxMyCustomMethod&token=d054ee102bdc9bb4bdf523478ea64b4f&

In JS i retrieve token like this:

```
   $.ajax({ 
        ajax : true,
        url: `https://myserver.eu/admin/index.php?controller=AdminMyModuleController&method=ajaxMyCustomMethod&token=` + window.employee_token,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: 'success',
        error: function () { 
            response([]);
        }
    });
```

However I'm receiving invalid Token error in response.

Can it be I'm retrieving token while being on site of another controller, and I'm sending AJAX to my controller, therefore (if token is generated from url or controller name) sent Token is different then expected one? So far I have failed to search where is token generated when it needs to be sent from JS file, so I don't know how it is generated, I only assume it is somehow from address. So far, I've found that Presta is using Bloodhound search engine, so I only found their tokenizers.

Comment: Sure seems strange to put JSON in url for a GET. Shouldn't this be a POST?

Comment: Yes, my fail. Changed in my repo and here to POST, thank you very much :) However this does not change anything with the token problem (looks like Presta does not care)

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am now facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, in the end I solved this. I dont remember too much, but I guess in the end I could read token from meta tag.